# Shortcut to view wireless networks in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, networking, shortcuts

Does anyone know how to create a shortcut which opens the wireless networks dialog box in Windows 7?  I'm looking for a shortcut that takes me directly to the window which shows you the available wireless networks around you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

create a new text file and put this on it

```
rundll32.exe van.dll,RunVAN
```

save it as "wifi.bat" and create a shortcut of it wherever you want,

right-click the shortcut, select propriety and edit its shortcut key to CTRL + ALT + W

now  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> will popup that *available Wireless network* window.

Or use any other trick to map a keyboard shortcut to it ...

Have fun

Comment: Tested and works on Win7, Thanks Revolter

Comment: If Explorer.exe isn't loaded, you might need to use `rundll32.exe van.dll,RunVANW` top get it top open up.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> is the built in key combination to get to the notification area. Then <kbd>right arrow</kbd> twice (or however many times you need) and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to show the available networks.

You could do this manually, or use [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to make your own single hotkey.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shortcut on your desktop via right mouse, New, Shortcut, Location:

```
C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}\::{38A98528-6CBF-4CA9-8DC0-B1E1D10F7B1B}
```

Press *Next* and name it "View Wireless Networks".

Then right click your shortcut and select properties, change Icon and select as file for "Look for Icons in this file" the following file:

```
%windir%\System32\wlanpref.dll
```

Select the icon you normally see in the lower right corner on the taskbar and press OK.

Answer (score 1):

The whole wifi.bat did not work for me... here is what worked

1. Click on Start
2. Click on Control Panel
3. Click on Network and Internet
4. Click on Network and Sharing Center
5. Choose Change adapter settings on the Task pane
6. Right-click on Wireless Network Connection - and drag it to Desktop and select create shortcut.
7. Right Click that shortcut and select properties and make a shortcut key (mine is "CTRL+ALT+W"

If Wifi is disabled this will turn it on instantly
If WiFi is enabled it will bring up connection window where you can press "Deactivate"